# MySQL master/slave replication - replicate all tables

Tags: mysql, replication

I am doing a master/slave replication, but getting errors about my tables does not exist. Is there not a way where i can make the whole table structure replicate aswell? Thought it did on default tbh.

Comment: Question #1) Are you using Magento ???

Comment: Question #2) When you run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`, what do `Replicate_Do_DB:`,`Replicate_Ignore_DB:`,`Replicate_Do_Table:`,`Replicate_Ignore_Table:`,`Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:` and `Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:` say ?

Comment: Nope. No CMS or e-commerce system. Custom PHP application.

Comment: Question #3) When you run `SELECT COUNT(1) TableCount FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema');` on the Master and on the Slave, how many tables do they have ?